# How can I make the CSS "inch" unit equal to a physical inch?

Tags: css

The CSS inch unit seems to be accurate until the user changes his/her screen resolution to something lower. I assume there are a number of potential users for any app who will have adjusted their screeen resolution for performance, and just to be consistent Im wondering if there's a way I can ensure that the CSS inch unit always matches a physical inch on the screen.

Comment: This looks relevant: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Absolute_length_units

Comment: an isolated unit "inch" makes little sense in a screen-medium context since different screens have differently sized pixels. My 21'' flat-screen runs 1980 px wide - just as my 15'' laptop

Answer (score 0):

Use @media for different resolutions to separate your css into blocks based on the ppi. You can get the device's screen resolution and determine the PPI from that. then one inch is = PPI.

PPI = Pixels per inch

use px instead of in. Also on average there are 96px/inch

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following utility (CSS polyfill) to help you do that:

https://www.toucaan.com/blog/meet-the-inch-css-utility-variable